# Is there a generalized notion of intrinsic charges which describes a general interaction?

Tags: forces, energy

Consider classical fields. Lots of parallels can be drawn between different kinds of fields because they are fundamentally similar. Mass can be viewed as a mass charge, [charge] can be viewed as an electric charge. Potentials, potential energies, and fields can all be described in terms of the relevant charge, other variables such as distances, and arbitrary constants.

I was wondering if anyone had ever formalised these ideas into a general structure for any formulation of an interaction which could be described by these variables and constants. Has it been done? What should I look into to find out more?

Comment: It seems you are you looking for [field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_field_theory), else I am unsure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The most successful attempt at a fundamental theory of the interactions in nature is the [Standard Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics.

In it, *every* interaction except for the self-interaction of Higgs is produced by it being a [*gauge theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory), and the generalization of charge is "simply" the specification in which [representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of the gauge group a given field transforms.

More generally, in a given [QFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), every summand in the Lagrangian can have a numerical prefactor, usually (if the term describes something other than the kinetic or mass term) called the *coupling strength*, which then indeed describes how large the contributions of that terms to a scattering amplitude are, and hence is a measure of the strength of interactions.

All of the above can essentially also be said in classical field theory.

Comment: Thanks. So is each numerical prefactor simply a coefficient which "weights" the effect of each force or is there more to it than that? Please pardon the un-technical lingo.

Comment: @PeterThomas: It indeed "simply weighs" the contribution of the term, but there are lots of subtleties involved - not every term actually produces something that looks like a "force", the terms that are relevant can change with the energy scale you are looking at, the coupling strengths get renormalized. The details are very much not straightforward.